# creating 100% standalone executable jar that doesn't require the java command

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, executable

so apparently if you create an executable jar, in order to run it you still need the java command:

```
java -jar something.jar
```

but what if I just want it to run without the java command, so just directly from the command line

```
something.jar
```

is there a way to export my java app in eclipse in order to accomplish such

Comment: no you cannot, .jar files are not executables but archives of executable (compiled) classes and resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 2024 update

According to
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excelsior_JET Huawei bought them in 2019 and took the product off the market.

However, Oracle now has GraalVM which can do something similar.  See https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/#build-a-native-executable for an introduction.

## 2011 answer

Excelsior JET - <s>http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html</s> - claims to compile to native code and bring its own runtime support, so it does not require an existing JVM.  Commercial product.

I have not tried it myself, but they have spent quite a bit of effort over the years to market JET as a great deployment method for precompiled binaries.

---

Also note that if you have an executable/runnable jar which works fine with "java -jar someting.jar" and you just want to be able to invoke it in a more convenient way, this is the job of the program accepting your command and launching the java command.

For Linux you can frequently add an alias saying that "something" expands to "java -jar something.jar", and some command interpreters allow for saying that all commands ending with jars should be executed specially.  The exact details depend on which shell (command line interpreter) you are using.

Comment: That link no longer goes to where it says it does. Now it opens a page about opening a small business..

Comment: @RobertMarkBram According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excelsior_JET they were bought by Huawei back in 2019.

Answer (score 4):

On Unix systems you can append the jar file at the end of an executable script.

On Windows you have to create a batch file.

For instance in Unix:

```
$cat HelloWorld.java  
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
         System.out.println("Hola mundo!");
    }
}
$cat M.mf 
Main-Class: HelloWorld
$cat hello
#!/bin/sh
exec java -jar $0 "$@"
$javac HelloWorld.java  
$jar -cmf M.mf  hello.jar HelloWorld.class 
$cat hello.jar >> hello 
$chmod +x hello
$./hello  
Hola mundo!
```

In windows you have to create a batch file like:

```
::hello.cmd 
javaw -jar hello.jar
```

Which has the same effect.

On Windows and OSX you can double click on the jar to run it, I'm pretty sure you may add a trigger on Linux too.

I hope this help

Comment: The reason the jar can be copied to the end of the shell script is because JAR is a special form of ZIP file, where the metadata needed to unpack it is unconventionally searched for from the _end_ of the file.  (This is most likely to be able to generate the contents on the fly and only write down the table of contents when done).  It still needs a JVM though to run.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a tool called 'Java Executable Wrapper'.You can use it to Pack all your class files to a Single Executable Package.

The One i recomment is launch4j,you can download it from sourceforge [launch4j.sourceforge.net](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net)

Launch4J can be used to create standalone Executables (.exe) from a jar file for windows Environment.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, that Java gets interpreted by the JVM, so you'll at least need to ship it with your app.

To be a little more specific about this, Java gets kind of compiled to byte-code so it can be interpreted faster. But the Byte-Code can't run without the JVM. This is the nice side of Java: You don't need to recompile your Apps to run on other platforms like Linux or OS X, the JVM takes care of that (as it is written in native code and is recompiled for those platforms).

There are some compilers out there which can convert your Java code to something native like C which can then be executed without the JVM. But this isn't the idea behind Java and most of those tools suck at what they do.

If you want your App to run without any interpreter, you'll need to use a compiled language like C or C++

Comment: A good tool can be used for more than what it was designed for - "this isn't the idea behind Java" can be discussed.  The original design was for providing downloadable but still verifyable code for settop boxes which is vastly different from running a large REST based Spring Boot backend these days.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen valid. Also note that this answer is now 13 years old. My views on this have changed :)

AFAIK most bigger tools that require Java to run either package it as a dependency if using a package manager or bundle the JRE directly in the ZIP file. Then, they use Shell scripts per platform to bootstrap everything.

This is easier now that OpenJDK is more up to date. There are fewer license issues with distributing it over the Oracle implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Java program runs on a JVM, for the first question I don't think there's a compiler that can do the job well. For the second question since a jar file is not an executable per se, there must be some sort of settings in the target machine, "executing" a jar file without providing the java command is a matter of convenience for the user. On Windows every file extension has a program associated with it, so .doc documents have (usually) Word as the program associated -that setting is set by the office installer, the java runtime also sets the setting for .jar files when you install it, but behind the scenes, java command will be used by the system. So the short answer to the second question is: depends on the target machine.