# How to create a *standalone* linux executable from java code

Tags: java, linux, executable

I know that java intent is for gui and multi platform, but the problem I'm facing it how to release a java application into a linux servers, which I don't have control on, i.e. I dont know what java vm is installed if at all.

So, how do i compile this into a true standalone linux exe, do not assume any pre installed package on the target linux.

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("You passed in: " + args[0]);

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to rather defeat the purpose of the cross platform capabilities of java.  Perhaps you should just write your application to be compatible with as broad a range of modern JVMs as possible (for example, compatible over java 5, 6, and 7 is relatively easy to do).

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating 100% standalone executable jar that doesn't require the java command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720161/creating-100-standalone-executable-jar-that-doesnt-require-the-java-command)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify as a requirement an installed JRE.
Otherwise you would need to deliver a JRE yourself as part of the deliverable application

Answer (score 1):

The [GNU COmpiler for Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java) does exactly this. Keep in mind that it will work properly only for small programs, either way you'll need a JVM.

There's also [Avian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avian_%28Java_virtual_machine%29), which has another approach and allows to deploy a lightweight JVM with jour application, but it still hasn't all the features of a full JRE.

Comment: One problem with the GNU Compiler for Java (gcj) is that it does not support Java 5 and newer features, or only part of them. It's not very useful for present day Java development.

Answer (score 1):

Creating one binary from java may not be that good. You may consider tools like http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ for creating a full installation along with appropriate jre.